# Domain of Orthogonality of Legendre Polynomials?

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

In my Numerical Analysis Course, under the topic Theory of Orthogonal Polynomials We are following the book Numerical Analysis by Kendall E Atkinson.

The problem is the author keeps saying "The Legendre Polynomials are orthogonal in $(-1,1)$"

According to me a polynomial is defined everywhere and is Orthogonal With respect to a Inner-product which might have some integral and limit.
It makes no sense for me to talk about orthogonality in a Domain.

The course is combined for Physics and Mathematics students and I am a Mathematics Major. 
Each Physics major believes the polynomial are orthogonal only in the domain.
for example Legendre polynomials are orthogonal in $(-1,1)$ only and you cant use them outside the $(-1,1)$ to study them or to find the coefficients using recursive relation outside $(-1,1)$ using Gaussian Elimination.

I want to know if there is meaning of Polynomials being orthogonal in a domain. If Yes, what does it mean?

Comment: How are you going to form the inner product without a domain? You could use a dot product, sure, but in the case of pair wise integration you need a domain in order to get a number out

Comment: The domain (-1,1) is defined for the Integral of the inner product not for the polynomial I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

> <s>"The Legendre Polynomials are orthogonal in (-1,1)"</s>

The Legendre Polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_\mathbb R w(x)f(x) g(x)\, dx$ for a [certain weight function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html) $w(x).$

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonality of Legendre polynomials is typically defined with respect to the inner product

$$
\langle p,q\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)\,dx
$$

Thus, they are said to be orthogonal on $(-1,1)$.
Of course, through a linear change of variables you could define them to be orthogonal on any bounded interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: The Polynomial $1$ and $1/2(3x^2 -1)$ are Orthogonal w.r.t. that Inner product that's it. what do you mean by orthogonal on $(-1,1)$

Comment: It simply means they are orthogonal with respect to the inner product given above, i.e., the integral defined on $(-1,1)$. If the integral was over $(a,b)$, then you would say they are orthogonal on $(a,b)$.

Comment: So do you mean that they stay orthogonal on $\mathbb{R}$ but we say they are orthogonal over (a,b) because it is the limit of the integral of the inner product. Is it a Standard Notation or Definition?

Comment: They are polynomials, so they are defined on $\mathbb{R}$, but they are not orthogonal on $\mathbb{R}$. Orthogonality is defined entirely with respect to the inner product which is defined on $(-1,1)$. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Sorry but it does not make it clear at all. Can you prove that Legendre Polynomials are not orthogonal over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The integral of $p_0(x)p_1(x) = x$ is divergent on $(0,\infty)$, and hence by definition it is divergent on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Thus these polynomials are not orthogonal on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I suppose we are not allowed to change the Inner product otherwise they won't be legendre polynomial anymore!

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that they are orthogonal with respect to the "uniform" probability distribution on $(-1,1)$, i.e. the measure $m$ defined by
$$
m(A) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } A = (-1,1), \\
0 & \text{if } A \text{ is disjoint from } (-1,1), \\
\cdots & \text{(see below for other sets.)}
\end{cases}
$$
The measure assigned by $m$ to intervals that are subsets of $(-1,1)$ is proportional to the length of the interval (and from the above you can see what the constant of proportionality is).

Answer (score 0):

they are orthogonal with respect to the inner product in the interval [-1,1],

Comment: In my opinion this does not answer to the question in the OP.